# Google doesn't index my pages managed by session

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, google-index

My website has an architecture like this:

- em1

  - sub1
  - sub2
  - ...
- em2

  - sub1
  - sub2
  - ...
- em3

  - ...
- ...

All elements "em" has the same "sub" associated. The difference only resides on the content in the "sub". The selected "em" is managed in the session. When the user enter on the website, the default selected is "em1". Google has indexed all subs in "em1", but not the "subs" in the other "em". Since there are links to change the "em" in the session, why did not Google index all my pages, and how can I fix it please?

Comment: Is `em2` accessed by a different URL? Or is the content that is served entirely controlled by the session, ie. the same URL. Google does not support sessions (ie. cookies), so anything that is dependent on a session cookie being set is not going to work.

Comment: The user can access the "em2" category by a link that changes session

Comment: (and that link has a different url) 
Exemple : /em1/sub1 will stock the "em1" in the session and bring you to content of "sub1" in "em1"
And /em2/sub2 will stock the "em2" in the session and bring you to content of "sub2" in "em2"

Comment: In that case, why do you need the "session"? If Google can find the URLs `/em1/sub1` and `/em2/sub2` without having to have a session variable set then it should be OK. (But I guess that is probably not the case?)

Comment: Are you using Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: w3dk : I need the session to register what "em" the user has chosen for his/her visit (and sadly Google doesn't find "em2/sub2", but it finds "/em2" url, which correspond to the "home page" of em2.
Norcal Johnny : Yes my website is registered with webmaster tool, the url is no blocked by robots (I aready check that if it's what your think about)

Comment: Can you give the actual URL for your website?   It is hard to know what is going on just from your description.

Comment: http://spectacles-publications.com/

Comment: list of "em" : "NANCY", "STRASBOURG", "DIJON", "METZ" (these are towns)
all "subs" are the elements in the menu ("concerts", "cinéma"...)
Google only indexed url with the town "NANCY" like 
"spectacles-publications.com/NANCY/articles/rubrique/CINEMA" (don't pay attention to "articles/rubrique/")
But none of the other town 
(example : "spectacles-publications.com/METZ/articles/rubrique/CINEMA" is not indexed)